# Slow compile time VueJS

Tags: vue.js, webpack

During development, we usually use hot reload an so on however, I am having problem due to very long compile time so every time I edit a single line of code, it takes about 10 seconds to compile. I read about using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) to speed up compile time but I don't know how to implement this in `vue.config.js`. I'll just post my `vue.config.js` although this won't help at all.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    open: 'Google Chrome',
    port: 8081,
    hot: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Vue uses webpack inside `vue.config.js`, so you can extend webpack configuration in `vue.config.js` if this is what you are looking for: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration

Comment: Thanks but I already know vue using webpack by default but I don't know how to implement the webpack's ddl plugin